# Validations within the SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis-2008

I currently have the following flow in an SSIS

[image]

My question is, is there any way to place an OLE DB, which allows me to insert information into a table called errors if Excel Source fails, in a few words, if the Excel file does not exist, I want to save 3 things in the table of errors, which would be, the date, an action and the message it produces. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it through Event Handler Tab in SSIS Paackage on the right of Parameters tab.

[image]

For further details, to accomplish your needs, please explore the Event Handler in SSIS, as you can see there is "OnError" right there, and there are plenty of options which occuring events that you may want to validate or make actions with, which also this including Error.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-event-handlers?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for the help Alfin E. R:, but I do not know what I'll be doing wrong, it throws the error screen (Package Validation Error), but it does not save the error, what I do is change the name of the excel file and ETL does nothing , the Event Handler is not activated.

Comment: Forget what I said before, I could, the ValidateExternalMetadata property was set to true, I changed it to false and the Event Handler was activated correctly, thanks for the help ...